# Pandas: Groupby and select evenly spaced rows

Tags: python, pandas

Below is my datafame sorted by video ID timestamp (the timestamp column have been removed for simplicity)

```
    cameraId      video
0  5B740319D  1508152851.mp4
1  5B740319D  1508152851.mp4
2  5B740319D  1508244253.mp4
3  5B740319D  1532963014.mp4
4  8B1602B07  1502607932.mp4
```

Each cameraId has 4-100 videos. I need to select 4 videos for each cameraId evenly spaced. Ex. if a cameraId has 100 videos, I should select video [0, 33, 66, 99]

This is my approach, select the first and last videos then randomly sample the middle 2.

```
first_video = df.drop_duplicates(['cameraId'], keep='first')
last_video = df.drop_duplicates(['cameraId'], keep='last')
middle_videos = df.groupby(['cameraId']).apply(lambda x: x.sample(2, random_state=seed)).reset_index(drop=True)
df = pd.concat([first_video, middle_videos, last_video])
```

The `middle_videos` usually isn't spaced evenly and that's where I'm stuck.

The output should be 4 rows for each cameraId

Comment: Add the output for above example.

Comment: The dataframe has 100k rows and the output would be 4 rows for each camera, that would be difficult to show.

Comment: So give the data with one `cameraId` with, e.g., 10 videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're always going to just want those 2 percentiles, one quick way is to just set up some small functions that you can aggregate on:

```
In [44]: df = pd.DataFrame({
    ...:     'id': [1] * 10 + [2] * 10 + [3] * 20,
    ...:     'file': ['f{}'.format(i) for i in range(10)] +
    ...:             ['f{}'.format(i) for i in range(10,20)] +
    ...:             ['f{}'.format(i) for i in range(20,40)]
    ...: })

In [45]: def pct33(s):
    ...:     return s.iloc[int(len(s) * .33)]
    ...:

In [46]: def pct66(s):
    ...:     return s.iloc[int(len(s) * .66)]
    ...:

In [47]: df.groupby('id').agg({'file': ['first', pct33, pct66, 'last']}).unstack()
Out[47]:
             id
file  first  1      f0
             2     f10
             3     f20
      pct33  1      f3
             2     f13
             3     f26
      pct66  1      f6
             2     f16
             3     f33
      last   1      f9
             2     f19
             3     f39
dtype: object
```

You can also drop the extra index levels or resort them later as desired.

Comment: wow I didn't know you can just call `first` and `last` like that. My desired output is obtained by removing the `unstack`

Comment: I'm curious, what if I wanted 10 videos evenly space, would I have to write 8 pct functions (`first, pct2, pct3,..., pct8, pct9 last`)

Comment: For more files, you could do something like `df.groupby("id").apply(lambda x: x.iloc[[int(len(x) * i/10) for i in range(10)]])` though that might need a little tweaking.

Comment: Actually, probably just changing the inner part to `int((len(x)-1) * i/10) for i in range(11)` will give what you want there